# VB.NET passing checked items values(parameters) to crystal report but it is only showing result(Report) for the last checked value in WinForms

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

The report is showing only the last checked value from the list as shown in the attached image any help ? I have been stuck there and nothing find helpful on the internet. Thanks in advance

**Here's the code**

```
        'Report variables
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

        'Load Report
        Dim crTestReport As New ReportDocument
        'Dim filePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "crTestReport.rpt"
        crTestReport.Load("crTestReport.rpt")

        'Parameteres
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = crTestReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions("@spaceid")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To Me.GridView1.RowCount - 1
            If Not IsDBNull(GridView1.GetDataRow(i).Item(3)) Then
                If GridView1.GetDataRow(i).Item(3) = True Then
                    crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue
                    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = GridView1.GetDataRow(i).Item(0)
                    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        crTestReport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "PASSWORD")

        frm.crReportViewer.ReportSource = crTestReport
        frm.crReportViewer.Refresh()
        frm.Show()
```

[image: Screen Shot Would Be helpful to understand better what i am saying]

Comment: its because you are passing ID as parameter which cannot be multiplied. you are passing one value only to there so it shows last one you pick.

Comment: any solution how can i achieve this?

Comment: you wanna get checked ones as report ?

Comment: yes i want a report for each checked item.

Comment: well then send parameter as where checked items which means `where select=1`